# How to calculate available disk space in linux machine using java?

Tags: java, linux, diskspace

I tried with File getFreeSpace() also which returns me 0. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/, http://www.ubuntu.com/ and http://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs should get you started

Answer (score 0):

How about the older org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

    double freeDiskSpace = org.apache.commons.io.FileSystemUtils.freeSpaceKb("/volume"); 
    double freeDiskSpaceGB = freeDiskSpace / 1024 / 1024;
    System.out.println("Free Disk Space (GB):" + freeDiskSpaceGB);

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System{" df -k | awk '{sum += $4 }i; END {print sum} '"};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public long getTotalSpace();
public long getFreeSpace();
public long getUsableSpace();
```

Each of these methods returns the requested size, in bytes, of the partition represented by the java.io.File **or 0L if a partition cannot be obtained from the File object**.
Can you report your code?